# Prisma DATABASE_URL error (Cloud Run + Cloud SQL)

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, prisma

I use [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) with Cloud Run & Cloud SQL. After providing `DATABASE_URL` to the `prisma.schema` it throws me an error in runtime.

```
Can't reach database server at `(/cloudsql/project-name:us-east1:database-id)`:`5432`
Please make sure your database server is running at `(/cloudsql/project-name:us-east1:database-id)`:`5432`."
```

- Database: Postgres
- Provided url `DATABASE_URL`: `postgresql://username:password@localhost/databasename?host=(/cloudsql/project-name:us-east1:database-id)`

What is wrong with connection? Do I failed to construct `DATABASE_URL` correctly?

Comment: Show your Cloud Run deployment and the deployment command.

Comment: @JohnHanley I was able to manage this issue on my own. The problem was in brackets around the `host` parameter in the connection URL. I posted my solution as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I removed brackets `()` around `host` parameter `/cloudsql/project-name:us-east1:database-id` and everything start to work as expected.

Before (with brackets)

```
postgresql://username:password@localhost/databasename?host=(/cloudsql/project-name:us-east1:database-id)
```

After (without brackets)

```
postgresql://username:password@localhost/databasename?host=/cloudsql/project-name:us-east1:database-id
```

Comment: For anyone who still has an error, my issue was incorrectly trying to connect to the "postgres" database. Create a new database for application data as suggested [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/create-manage-databases)