# What is the Postgres DATABASE_URL to connect cloud run to postgres on cloud SQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, database-connection, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I am trying to connect my cloud run app to cloud sql, here is my cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  env:
    - DATABASE_URL=$_DATABASE_URL
  entrypoint: npx
  dir: './server'
  args:
    - 'prisma'
    - 'migrate'
    - 'deploy'
```

However, I keep on getting the error `Please make sure your database server is running at '/cloudsql/learninfra001:us-central1:learninfra001-postgres':'5432'.`
Here is the _DATABASE_URL I use for substitution variable `postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/db?schema=public&host=/cloudsql/learninfra001:us-central1:learninfra001-postgres`
I have made sure the following:

- The default cloud run service account has Cloud SQL Client role
- The database `db` is created
- Within the cloudrun service, under connections, the Cloud SQL connections is pointing to the correct instance (learninfra001:us-central1:learninfra001-postgres)

Using white-listed public IP, I am able to connect to the DB. However, I just can't seem to get cloud run to work. Is there anything else I could check? Or is there a way to get more logging to see why it is not connecting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prisma DATABASE\_URL error (Cloud Run + Cloud SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67976986/prisma-database-url-error-cloud-run-cloud-sql)

Comment: Hey @RobertG I updated my question. Unfortunately that didn't work for me. Do you have any other ideas I could try?

Comment: for mysql for my database_url secret/env variable - I had to add the query string ?socket=/cloudsql/{connectionname}  
connection name being the instance name you can copy from the console in cloud sql

Answer (score 2):

In short, you'll need to enable a Cloud SQL connection to your Cloud SQL instance from Cloud Build.

See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-build for details.

Comment: I tried to use this but it still unable to connect. This is the link that I tried to use. 
`postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/db?schema=public&host=/cloudsql/learninfra001:us-central1:learninfra001-postgres`
I have made sure service account has cloud sql client role and that cloud run cloudsql connections is pointing to the right cloud sql instance. During cloud build, I am still getting `Please make sure your database server is running at '/cloudsql/learninfra001:us-central1:learninfra001-postgres':'5432'.`

What else should I look into? @enocom

Comment: Looks like you're trying to connect to Cloud SQL from Cloud Build (not Cloud Run). Your URL will work for Cloud Run. For Cloud Build see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-build where you can enable the Cloud SQL Proxy as part of your migrate step.

Comment: Got it to work! You are amazing!  cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-build  is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @MaxYuan can you share your solution?

Comment: @Kromel like the sql string format?

Comment: - id: 'migrate-socket-and-migrate-db'
    name: '${_IMAGE_NAME}-proxy'
    dir: './server'
    entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        set -a
        source .env
        set +a
        /cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy -instances=$$SQL_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME -dir=/cloudsql & sleep 2;
        npx prisma migrate deploy